# Can I make Resharper align case clauses in switch statements on one line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

*(Note: [This, 7-year-old reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135190/5869304) refers to a [JetBrains request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-388810) for this feature which was subsequently marked as "done" in 2017.  But they've rearranged their Options dialog since then and I cannot find the equivalent.  So I am posting again)*

I'm typing a switch statement in C#.  When the case statements are short, I generally want to line them up in columns because it makes the code easier to grasp at a glance.  So for example, I might want it look like this

```
switch (XyLengthUnit)
{
case LengthUnit.CM: _precision = 6; break;
case LengthUnit.MM: _precision = 3; break;
}
```

And mostly it works.  But every time I get to the end of a line and type the semicolon, Resharper insists on moving the `break` down to the next line

```
switch (XyLengthUnit)
{
case LengthUnit.CM: _precision = 6; break;
case LengthUnit.MM: _precision = 3; 
    break;    
}
```

So I have to hit backspace to fix it.  Every time.

I am sure that it is Resharper doing this because when I disable it, the behavior stops and my 'break' statement remains on the same line.

I've gone through every single setting under Resharpers *Options >> Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Tabs, Indents, Alignment* Nothing there seems to change this.  I found a few settings under "Line Breaks and Wrapping that *seemed* appropriate (and related the previously mentioned feature request) but they did not change the behavior

[image]

(This is how I have the settings now but I've monkeyed with them extensively.  They do not seem to change anything.  As soon as I hit semicolon, the `break` gets moved)

I know that many Resharper settings have "hard breaks" at a certain column and all that but I generally set those to really high numbers (e.g. column 150).

Is there a setting for it that I am missing?  Is it possible to make Resharper align things like this?

Comment: Look at [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) which has nothing to do with Resharper other than when using a switch statement if possible Resharper will provide an option to change to a switch expression.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  However I am familiar with the switch expression.  But I do have cases where I need to use a regular switch statement.  The example I wrote was just a simplified version of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible right now. The "Place simple case statements" takes effect when there's only one statement inside a case section, where's in your case there are two including the `break;` statement.